# How to count which bracket is unbalance?

Tags: python

In a program to check whether the brackets are balanced or not? My program runs correctly it does its work.Only problem that i am facing right now is that i cant count which bracket is mismatch. For example in given below input

```
[ ] ( ( )
```

output must be

```
3
```

because the 3rd bracket is unmatched.But acc to my code its

```
5
```

because the 4th bracket closing is missing which should be at place 5

So anyone please help me to understand how can I do it

Here is a part of my code that does the work

```
for i in n:
    if i in "{([":
        arr.append(i)
        count += 1
    elif i in "})]":
        if len(arr) == 0:
            flag = 0
            break
        temp = arr.pop()
        if i == "}" and temp == "{" :
            count += 1
            continue
        elif i == ")" and temp == "(":
            count += 1
            continue
        elif i == "]" and temp == "[":
            count += 1
            continue
        else:
            flag = 0
            break
```

And at last print count

Comment: If you post your code, someone might be able to tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [stack](https://realpython.com/how-to-implement-python-stack/) to track which braces you have seen. You should push to the stack on an opening brace, and pop from it on a closing brace. As you parse each brace, make a note of its index in the string (e.g. by pushing not just the brace type onto the stack, but maybe a tuple of the character and its index, something like `('[', 1)` or `('(', 3)`. Once you have finished parsing, the only things left on the stack will be the unmatched braces along with their indices.